# How to use Javascript or jquery in 1 page website for page change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a website Front-end and back-end and wondering how to call js/jquery to change pages within a one-page website

Tabs/pages I have Home / About / Special Offers / Contact

I have tried using javascript style.display but is only doing the four pages 
Home / About / Special Offers / Contact and only if I start with the about page it will work and home just refreshes the page and I have the code to detect the new sections by id but can't keep changing them like how I would like to do

I tried to work with PHP to save $currentpage and save $nextpage so that way it would change pages/sections based on the PHP values I don't get an error from PHP I think I have something wrong with my PHP code or js code

```
JS Code 

<script type="text/javascript">
function show(show, hide) {
document.getElementById(hide).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(show).style.display = "block";
}
</script>


Section Code

Home <section id="home" class="large-9 columns" style="display:none"></section>

About <section id="about" class="large-9 columns" style="display:none"></section>

Special Offers <section id="specials" class="large-9 columns" style="display:none"></section>

Contact <section id="contact" class="large-9 columns" style="display:none"></section>


onclick js Event Code

<a href="<?PHP echo $unsecure;?>://<?PHP echo $domain?>" title="Home">Home</a>

<a href="#About" title="About" onclick="return show('about', '<?PHP echo $currentpage;?>') <?PHP if($nextpage = 'about'){ $currentpage = $nextpage;}?>">About</a>

<a href="#Special_Offers" title="Special Offers" onclick="return show('specials', '<?PHP echo $currentpage;?>') <?PHP if($nextpage = 'specials'){ $currentpage = $nextpage;}?>">Special Offers</a>

<a href="#contact" title="contact" onclick="return show('contact', '<?PHP echo $currentpage;?>') <?PHP if($nextpage = 'contact'){ $currentpage = $nextpage;}?>">Contact</a>
```

Expected:
I would like to be able to use js or jquery to change the display style from block to none when clicked just like it be correct like changing pages but in a one-page site and be able to add more pages to work with it also.

Actual Results:
When I refresh the page on my site I can click About and Contact and will show up correctly but when I click about again it shows it below Contact and doesn't hide Contact

When I refresh the page I click Special Offers it just places underneath the main  which is home and doesn't hide the main section

Comment: That's the only PHP code you have? If so, it's not needed. You just need to search the internet on how to load content with jQuery.load. On jQuery's website are examples of how to do what You want :) -> https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank You so much i looked into it i didnt even iknow i could do that this is so cool thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that really helped out was jQuery.load. I had no idea about that that was so much simpler than what I originally had by trying to make in in js from scratch and load I don't have to have extra PHP in my index.php file

All i had to do was

`onclick='$("#main").load("includes/file.php")'`

and works like a charm